# Error when using ggstatsplot - Error in 'mutate()': Caused by error in vapply()':

Tags: r

Just installed ggstatsplot and tried running the Example in the Documentation to just see what inputs it requires and how to manipulate the function.

```
library(ggstatsplot) 
ggbetweenstats(mtcars, am, mpg)
```

I was immediately met with the error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `n_label = paste0(am, "\n(n = ", .prettyNum(n), ")")`.
Caused by error in `vapply()`:
! values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 3
```

I have tried multiple examples I found online of how to use the package and all result in the same error. I also tried ggwithinstats and received the same error. I updated all of my packages and have restarted R Studio at each step.

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if I can provide any other information.

Comment: See this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/issues/749) for the reason and a possible workaround.

Comment: Like Stefan said, you will need to update to the GitHub versions of the packages until these updates make it to CRAN. I am trying to update them, but this usually takes some time.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the point in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the troubles.

This is due to update to *insight* package (https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/issues/749).

**EDIT on 21 May 22:**

Both *statsExpressions* and *ggstatsplot* updates are now on CRAN, so all these issues should go away.

Comment: Was able to get it working. Thanks, appreciate the package!

Answer (score 1):

I get the exact same error.

```
#for reproducibility and data
set.seed(123)
library(WRS2)
library(ggstatsplot)

ggwithinstats(
  data = bugs_long,
  x = condition,
  y = desire
)
```

May it is a bug?